# Installing Flash Debugger in Chrome Issue

Tags: actionscript, google-chrome, flash

I need to test flash site using Flash Debugger version 10.1  in Google Chrome.

Issue:
cannot able to view debug version of flash player.

Steps Done:

1. Disabled integrated version of flash player by listing through "about:plugins".( Note: I saw adobe document stated that it has two plugins integrated and system. But can able to see only integrated plug-in).
2. Installed Flash player 10.1 plugin content debugger from Adobe http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html.
3. I tried to see the list of plugins through "about:plugins". But I cannot able to find the installed debugger in the list to enable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going to about:plugins , click on the "Details" link on the right , the plugins list will expand and you should be able to see both Flash plugins and disable the default one.

Comment: Thanks patrick. But I saw disabled both under flash plugins. After that I installed Flash player 10.1 plugin content debugger from Adobe. But new installed one doesn't show in the "about:plugins" list. While installing also, it never ask to close chrome browser. Anything that I am missing.

Comment: If they're both disabled , clicking "Disabled" on the debugger version should enable it, at least that's what happening with my version of Chrome. If this doesn't work, check that you have the latest Chrome update...

Answer (score 0):

Workaround #1 worked for me here: http://www.timo-ernst.net/2010/04/chrome-flash-debugger-not-connecting-to-flexflash-builder/

And you can check your current flash player version at: www.flashplayerversion.com